# Notepad++ IDL Syntax Highlighting?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, idl, idl-programming-language

I was about to create a user-defined language file for Notepad++ to syntax-highlight [IDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDL_%28programming_language%29) (Interactive Data Language).  But before I went and spent the time creating one, I wanted to check with the "community" to see if anyone else has one that's ready to go.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Googling for "notepad++ idl" gives me http://pocaracas.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/idl-syntax-highlighting-in-notepad/

Comment: @Thomas, the link you give is not for the same IDL language. The XML in Philip answer is the right one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[IDL syntax highlighting in Notepad++](http://pocaracas.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/idl-syntax-highlighting-in-notepad/)

Here's the XML:

```xml
<NotepadPlus>
    <UserLang name="IDL" ext="pro">
        <Settings>
            <Global caseIgnored="no" />
            <TreatAsSymbol comment="yes" commentLine="no" />
            <Prefix words1="no" words2="yes" words3="yes" words4="no" />
        </Settings>
        <KeywordLists>
            <Keywords name="Delimiters">&quot;&apos;0&quot;&apos;0</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folder+">begin of pro function ;+</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folder-">endfor endif endwhile endrep endcase endswitch end ;-</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Operators">$ &amp; ( ) / [ ] { } =</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Comment"> 1;+ 2;- 0;</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Words1">if then else for do while repeat until break case switch common continue exit return goto help message print read retall stop</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Words2">a_correlate abs acos adapt_hist_equal alog alog10 amoeba arg_present arra_equal array_indices ascii_template asin assoc atan beseli beselj besel k besely beta bilinear bin_date binary_template dinfgen dinomial blk_con broyden bytarr byte bytscl c_correlate call_external call_function ceil chebyshev check_math chisqr_cvf chisqr_pdf choldc cholsol cindgen clust_wts cluster color_quan colormap_applicable comfit complex complexarr complexround compute_mesh_normals cond congrid conj convert_coord convol coord2to3 correlate cos cosh cramer create_struct crossp crvlength ct_luminance cti_test curvefit cv_coord cvttobm cw_animate cw_arcball cw_bgroup cw_clr_index cw_colorsel cw_defroi cw_field cw_filesel cw_form cw_fslider cw_light_editor cw_orient cw_palette_editor cw_pdmenu cw_rgbslider cw_tmpl cw_zoom dblarr dcindgen dcomplexarr defroi deriv derivsig determ diag_matrix dialog_message dialog_pickfile pialog_printersetup dialog_printjob dialog_read_image dialog_write_image digital_filter dilate dindgen dist double eigenql eigenvec elmhes eof erode erf erfc erfcx execute exp expand_path expint extrac extract_slice f_cvf f_pdf factorial fft file_basename file_dirname file_expand_path file_info file_same file_search file_test file_which filepath findfile findgen finite fix float floor fltarr format_axis_values fstat fulstr fv_test fx_root fz_roots gamma gauss_cvf gauss_pdf gauss2dfit gaussfit gaussint get_drive_list get_kbrd get_screen_size getenv grid_tps grid3 griddata gs_iter hanning hdf_browser hdf_read hilbert hist_2d hist_equal histogram hough hqr ibeta identity idl_validname idlitsys_createtool igamma imaginary indgen int_2d int_3d int_tabulated intarr interpol interpolate invert ioctl ishft julday keword_set krig2d kurtosis kw_test l64indgen label_date label_region ladfit laguerre la_cholmprove la_cholsol la_Determ la_eigenproblem la_eigenql la_eigenvec la_elmhes la_gm_linear_model la_hqr la_invert la_least_square_equality la_least_squares la_linear_equation la_lumprove la_lusol la_trimprove la_trisol leefit legendre linbcg lindgen linfit ll_arc_distance lmfit lmgr lngamma lnp_test locale_get logical_and logical_or logical_true lon64arr lonarr long long64 lsode lu_complex lumprove lusol m_correlate machar make_array map_2points map_image map_patch map_proj_forward map_proj_init map_proj_inverse matrix_multiply matrix_power max md_test mean meanabsdev median memory mesh_clip mesh_decimate mesh_issolid mesh_merge mesh_numtriangles mesh_smooth mesh_surfacearea mesh_validate mesh_volume min min_curve_surf moment morph_close morph_distance morph_gradient morph_histormiss morph_open morph_thin morph_tophat mpeg_open msg_cat_open n_elements n_params n_tags newton norm obj_class obj_isa obj_new obj_valid objarr p_correlate path_sep pcomp pnt_line polar_surface poly poly_2d poly_area poly_fit polyfillv ployshade primes product profile profiles project_vol ptr_new ptr_valid ptrarr qgrid3 qromb qromo qsimp query_bmp query_dicom query_image query_jpeg query_mrsid query_pict query_png query_ppm query_srf query_tiff query_wav r_correlate r_test radon randomn randomu ranks read_ascii read_binary read_bmp read_dicom read_image read_mrsid read_png read_spr read_sylk read_tiff read_wav read_xwd real_part rebin recall_commands recon3 reform region_grow regress replicate reverse rk4 roberts rot rotate round routine_info rs_test s_test savgol search2d search3d sfit shift shmdebug shmvar simplex sin sindgen sinh size skewness smooth sobel sort sph_scat spher_harm spl_init spl_interp spline spline_p sprsab sprsax sprsin sprstp sqrt standardize stddev strarr strcmp strcompress stregex string strjoin strlen strlowcase strmatch strmessage strmid strpos strsplit strtrim strupcase svdfit svsol swap_endian systime t_cvf t_pdf tag_names tan tanh temporary tetra_clip tetra_surface tetra_volume thin timegen tm_test total trace transpose tri_surf trigrid trisol ts_coef ts_diff ts_fcast ts_smooth tvrd uindgen unit uintarr ul64indgen ulindgen ulon64arr ulonarr ulong ulong64 uniq value_locate variance vert_t3d voigt voxel_proj warp_tri watershed where widget_actevix widget_base widget_button widget_combobox widget_draw widget_droplist widget_event widget_info widget_label widget_list widget_propertsheet widget_slider widget_tab widget_table widget_text widget_tree write_sylk wtn xfont xregistered xsq_test</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Words3">annotate arrow axis bar_plot blas_axpy box_cursor breakpoint byteorder caldata calendar call_method call_procedure catch cd cir_3pnt close color_convert compile_opt constrained_min contour copy_lun cpu create_view cursor cw_animate_getp cw_animate_load cw_animate_run cw_light_editor_get cw_light_editor_set cw_palette_editor_get cw_palette_editor_set define_key define_msgblk define_msgblk_from_file defsysv delvar device dfpmin dissolve dlm_load doc_librar draw_roi efont empty enable_sysrtn erase errplot expand file_chmod file_copy file_delete file_lines file_link file_mkdir file_move file_readlink flick flow3 flush forward_function free_lun funct gamma_ct get_lun grid_input h_eq_ct h_eq_int heap_free heap_gc hls hsv icontour iimage image_cont image_statistics internal_volume iplot isocontour isosurface isurface itcurrent itdelete itgetcurrent itregister itreset ivolume journal la_choldc la_ludc la_svd la_tridc la_triql la_trired linkimage loadct ludc make_dll map_continents map_grid map_proj_info map_set mesh_obj mk_html_help modifyct mpeg_close mpeg_put mpeg_save msg_cat_close msg_cat_compile multi obj_destroy on_error on_ioerror online_help openr openw openu oplot oploterr particle_trace path_cache plot plot_3dbox plot_field ploterr plots point_lun polar_contour polyfill polywarp popd powell printf printd ps_show_fonts psafm pseudo ptr_free pushd qhull rdpix readf read_interfile read_jpeg read_pict read_ppm read_srf read_wave read_x11_bitmap reads readu reduce_colors register_cursor replicate_inplace resolve_all resolve_routine restore save scale3 scale3d set_plot set_shading setenv setup_keys shade_surf shade_surf_irr shade_volume shmmap show3 showfont skip_lun slicer3 slide_image socket spawn sph_4pnt streamline stretch strput struct_assign struct_hide surface surfr svdc swap_enian_inplace t3d tek_color threed time_test2 triangulate triql trired truncate_lun tv tvcrs tvlct tvscl usersym vector_field vel velovect voronoi wait wdelete wf_draw widget_control widget_displaycontextmenu window write_bmp write_image write_jpeg write_nrif write_pict write_png write_ppm write_spr write_srf write_tiff write_wav write_wave writeu wset wshow xbm_edit xdisplayfile xdxf xinteranimate xloadct xmanager xmng_tmpl xmtool xobjview xobjview_rotate xobjview_write_image xpalette xpcolo xplot3d xroi xsurface xvaredit xvolume xyouts zoom zoom_24</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Words4"></Keywords>
        </KeywordLists>
        <Styles>
            <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" styleID="11" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Arial" fontStyle="0" fontSize="10" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDEROPEN" styleID="12" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Arial Black" fontStyle="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDERCLOSE" styleID="13" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Arial Black" fontStyle="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORD1" styleID="5" fgColor="8000FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Arial" fontStyle="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORD2" styleID="6" fgColor="0000FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Arial" fontStyle="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORD3" styleID="7" fgColor="008080" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Arial" fontStyle="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORD4" styleID="8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="COMMENT" styleID="1" fgColor="004000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Arial" fontStyle="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="COMMENT LINE" styleID="2" fgColor="008000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Arial" fontStyle="2" />
            <WordsStyle name="NUMBER" styleID="4" fgColor="400000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Arial" fontStyle="1" />
            <WordsStyle name="OPERATOR" styleID="10" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Arial" fontStyle="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMINER1" styleID="14" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Arial" fontStyle="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMINER2" styleID="15" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Arial" fontStyle="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMINER3" styleID="16" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" />
        </Styles>
    </UserLang>
</NotepadPlus>
```

Comment: The link in this answer refers to a different IDL language, not the Interactive Data Language in the question. But the XML given here is correct.